# Why doesn't this code delete all items from the Android calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to delete all entries from Android calendar,but i didn't work.

Source code:

```
ContentResolver ContentRes = getContentResolver();
Uri calUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
int id = 1;
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(calUri, id);
ContentRes.delete(uri, null,null);
```

Comment: Please try not to prefix all of your questions with "Android:" that's what the tags are for.

Comment: Please try not to use content providers that are not part of the SDK and that you're not supposed to be using. Use the Google Calendar GData API to manipulate the user's calendar, please.